# Php Variable definition in database

Tags: php

Hi I have too loop through code several times but rather than having to keep changing the code I thought it would be easier to store my variable definitions in db table.

So my definition of title should be

```
$title=$feed->items[0]['title'];
```

So I stored

```
$feed->items[0]['title'];
```

In my table and looked it up. However when I then look it up from the table and say.

```
$title=$valueFromTable;
```

Then title actually = "$feed->items[0]['title'];"

Rather than the title of the first item. Is there a way to do this or can you not store variable definitions in tables for reference?

Thanks.

As requested my query is

```
$rssName='Chatham House';
$sql="SELECT * FROM `tbl_rss_feeds`     WHERE `rssName`='$rssName'";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(); 

while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
$url=$row->rssAddress;
$title1=$row->title1;
}
```

So now when I want to say

```
$title=$feed->items[0]['title'];
```

so it gets the first title value of the feed. The problem is that $title now just stores this a text rather than it being a definition.

Comment: please post your query

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to store, the value of `$feed->items[0]['title']` or the actual PHP-code? If it is the code... then don't! Just like @AnatPort asked, show us your query.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I'm trying to store the actually php code. Is this not possible then? I have added the query to the question. Thanks.

Comment: You can store PHP in the DB, but you need to run it through `eval()` to execute it, and it won't contain the data it once did so in that regard, it won't work. Either way, storing PHP-code in the DB is really a very bad practice. It will be a pain to maintain..

Comment: Basically I have a list off RSS feeds that will be increase over time. The data from the feeds will be stored in a table. The feeds are all slightly different so rather than having to edit the php file each time I add a new feed I wanted to be able to store the feeds and variable definitions in a table and loop through.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson is there another way to achieve this that you know of?